# NLP using replacement tokens

Tags: python, nlp, text-classification

I read a lot of articles that deal with different NLP classification tasks and I saw that most of them specify in the pre-processing section that they use replacement tokens:

> e.g. We removed and replaced the URLs, emojis and punctuation with replacement tokens: `<URL>, <EMOJI>, <PUNCT>`.

I am quite new to this domain and I was wondering if there is some special way to deal with this kind of tokens/tags? Is it necessary to use `< >` or is this just a way to signal this replacement and for helping the classifier in finding a pattern?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: it is common to do that so you know for example <URL> is not the same if you happened to have the word `url` in your text

Answer (score 1):

From what I did, in the pre-processing section, people replace all tokens (chars, morphemes, words) with numbers. These replacement tokens are nothing but **numbers** as well, `<URL>` is just a way to present it to humans.